# Java 8 perform sum operation in nested lists with filter option

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Lets assume I have the following construct:

```
public class Athlete {
    private String      name;
    private int         someIdentifier;
    private Double      height;
    private Double      weight;
    private List<Shoes> shoes;
    // getters
    // setters
    public class Shoes {
        private String  name;
        private boolean ball;
        private int     someNumber;
        private int     someOtherNumber;
        // getters
        // setters
    }
}
```

I have a list from my first iteration gathered here `List<Athlete> athleteList`

Now I create a new Athlete objects and I want to check if they already exist in my list and if they do I want to perform an addition to some fields.

I have tried the following which works fine:

```
athleteList.stream()
                     .filter(at -> filterAthlete(at, newAthlete))
                     .map(at -> mergeAthletes(at, newAthlete))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

private boolean filterAthlete(Athlete firstAthlete, Athlete secondAthlete) {
        if (firstAthlete.getName().equals(secondAthlete.getName())
                && firstAthlete.getSomeIdentifier() ==   secondAthlete.getSomeIdentifier()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

private Athlete mergeAthletes(Athlete firstAthlete, Athlete secondAthlete) {

        for (Shoes firstShoe : firstAthlete.getShoes()) {
            for (Shoes secondShoe : secondAthlete.getShoes()) {
                if (firstShoe.getBrand().equals(secondShoe.getBrand()) && firstShoe.getColor().equals(secondShoe.getColor())) {
                    firstShoe.setSomeNumber(firstShoe.getSomeNumber() + secondShoe.getSomeNumber());
                    firstShoe.setSomeOtherNumber(firstShoe.getSomeOtherNumber() + secondShoe.getSomeOtherNumber());
                }
            }
        }

        return firstAthlete;
    }
```

But I would like to find a way to use stream() in my mergeAthletes(...) method.

I thought of doing something like that:

```
BiConsumer<Shoes, Shoes> reducer = (shoe1, shoe2) -> {
            shoe1.setSomeNumber(shoe1.getSomeNumber() + shoe2.getSomeNumber());
            shoe1.setSomeOtherNumber(shoe1.getSomeOtherNumber() + shoe2.getSomeOtherNumber());
        };

        Function<Shoes, List<Object>> compositeKey = shoes -> Arrays.<Object> asList(shoes.getBrand(),
                shoes.getColor());
```

In my mergeAthletes method, use the *Function* in place of my if-condition and the *BiConsumer* in place of the the addition in the double for each loop, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely putting your `Athlete`s into a map would be more efficient?

Comment: @JoeC maybe, but that would also mean changing my database schema. So lets say this is the way its supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
firstAthlete.getShoes().forEach(shoe1 ->
    secondAthlete.getShoes().stream().filter(shoe2 -> 
        shoe1.getBrand().equals(shoe2.getBrand()) && shoe1.getColor().equals(shoe2.getColor()))
    ).forEach(shoe2 -> {
        shoe1.setSomeNumber(shoe1.getSomeNumber() + shoe2.getSomeNumber());
        shoe1.setSomeOtherNumber(shoe1.getSomeOtherNumber() + shoe2.getSomeOtherNumber());
    })
```

If your shoes were immutable (no `set...` methods), *then* you'd use `reduce` instead of the second `forEach` and probably `map` instead of the first one, depending on your requirements.

(Also, `firstAthlete.getName() == secondAthlete.getName()` is very likely an error and you want `equals` there like when comparing shoes.)

Comment: Thanks mate. Yeah the string comparison was a mistake of mine, because I was writing a dummy object. In the second forEach though you mean firstShoe instead of shoe1 and secondShoe instead of shoe2, right? I changed it and it works as expected. Thanks again!